# If .antMatcher is the first method after http then default login gives 404 but why?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Using spring-boot v2.0.0M3, I want to use the default login page provided by spring-security and also want to have 2 different end points with different security config just like explained here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

My full security configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    public ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/v1/**")
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this::commence)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
class NonApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/manage/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
            .and().formLogin();
    }

}
```

**For the second part:** Following config works and it redirects users to login page and the default login page is shown:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/manage/**")
    .hasRole("USER")
    .and().formLogin();
```

However following config gives `404` for `/login` after successfully redirecting user to login:

```
http
    .antMatcher("/manage/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .hasRole("USER")
    .and().formLogin();
```

Why is that? I think both combination should work, I can't find anything in docs that hints this would not work.

Comment: Those are 2 different configurations... The first secures all urls and secures the `/manage` starting urls. However the latter applies the security ONLY to `/manage` starting URLs including the login form.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is intended. I think I couldn't explain my intention clearly so I've updated the question.

Comment: As stated in my comment those are different configurations. This has nothing to with your question not being clear.

Comment: yeah I get they are different. the question is _why default login page gives 404 with the last example config?`

Comment: Have you read my comment? Because that only applies to urls starting with `/manage`... This now includes your login page.

Answer (score 0):

create a new **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class with default formlogin settings.

`http.formLogin();` inside the configure method, which creates default `/login` page.

**Explanation:** This is expected because the first antMatchers states that the entire HttpSecurity is only going to work if it starts with `/manage/` and the formLogin is by default going to be `/login`. To resolve the issue you need to follow the above work around.